# How to increase space between tabulars inside a table

Tags: tables

I have a table with six tabular inside. They all belong to one problem and caption.

I positioned them with \hfill, which works ok, but there could be more space between the two rows of tabular. \hspace did not work.

How can I increase the space?

Here is my TeX

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      \bm{$K_0$} & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & 1 & X & X \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & 1 & 1 & X & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      \bm{$J_0$} & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & X & 1 & 0 \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & X & X & 1 & 1 \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      \bm{$K_1$}  & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & X & X & X & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      \bm{$J_1$}  & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & X & X & X \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      \bm{$K_2$}  & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & X & X & 1 \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & 0 & X & 0 & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      \bm{$J_2$}  & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & 1 & X & X \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & X & X & 0 & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like
[image: Example of my tables]

Comment: Replace the third `\hfill` directive with an all-blank line (to induce a paragraph break) followed by `\bigskip` before the next `\begin{tabular}`. Oh, and omit the `\centering` objective since it doesn't do anything in your setup.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(re-posting my earlier comment as an answer, so that this query can be considered to have received an "official" answer).

To achieve your formatting objective, you should replace the third `\hfill` directive with an all-blank line (to induce a paragraph break) followed by `\bigskip` before the next instance of `\begin{tabular}`.

Some additional comments: (i) You may (actually, should) omit the `\centering` directive as it doesn't do anything in the your setup. (ii) The sixth and final `\hfill` directive should be deleted (or commented out). (iii) `\bm` (short for "bold math") should be employed only in math mode; hence, do replace `\bm{$K_0$}` with `$\bm{K_0}$`, `\bm{$J_0$}` with `$\bm{J_0}$`, etc. (iv) Using `[H]` to force the placement of the `table` "**right here, damn it!**" can actually be counterproductive; use `[ht!]` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[a4paper, vmargin=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    %\centering % <-- not needed
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      $\bm{K_0}$ & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & 1 & X & X \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & 1 & 1 & X & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      $\bm{J_0}$ & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & X & 1 & 0 \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & X & X & 1 & 1 \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      $\bm{K_1}$  & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & X & X & X & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}

    \bigskip % <-- new, in lieu of \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      $\bm{J_1}$  & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & X & X & X \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & 1 & 1 & 0 & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      $\bm{K_2}$  & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & X & X & 1 \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & 0 & X & 0 & X \\
      \hline
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
      $\bm{J_2}$  & $Q_0$ & $Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ & $\bar Q_0$ \\
      \hline
      $Q_1$      & X & 1 & X & X \\
      $\bar Q_1$ & X & X & 0 & X \\
      \hline 
      & $Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $\bar Q_2$ & $ Q_2$ 
    \end{tabular}
    %\hfill % <-- not needed either
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your afford here!